# How to substract 1 month from selected date with the right format

Tags: javascript

I want to substract 1 month from the selected date and get it in this format `mm/dd/yyyy`

```
self.SelectedDate = "02/22/2018";
var temp = new Date(self.SelectedDate);
    temp.setDate(temp.getDate() - 30);
```

but the result I get is `Mon Jan 08 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)`

This is just a very small part in my program so I don't want to download a library just for this. I am using AngularJS, is there a way to get what I want without downloading or adding angular filters?

Comment: Because you have a date object now, you can use some library like momentjs to format it back to a string. Another option is you can manually format it

Comment: As much as libraries seem to be frowned upon, dates can be a real PITA. Do as recommended above. Use a library .. moment.js is excellent ... if you'll need multiple timezones, look at moments timezone library as well

Comment: @ArunPJohny I am using AngularJS but I don't want to use any filters. What is the way to format it manually?

Comment: Why not use a filter? But if you can't and don't want to use any other library, you can use a custom function, like `function formatDate(date) {
      var dt = date.getDate(),
        mon = date.getMonth() + 1,
        yy = date.getFullYear();
      let value = (mon < 9 ? '0' : '0') + mon;
      value += '/' + (dt < 9 ? '0' : '') + dt;
      value += '/' + yy;
      return value;
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) does not accept a string in this format.

```js
self.SelectedDate = "02/22/2018";
var p = self.SelectedDate.split("/");
var temp = new Date(p[2],p[0]-1,p[1]);
    temp.setDate(temp.getDate() - 30);
const pad = n=>("0"+n).slice(-2);
var f = [pad(temp.getMonth()+1),pad(temp.getDate()),temp.getFullYear()].join("/");
console.log(f);
```

Comment: The result I got is `1/23/118`, How to get `1/23/2018` ?

Comment: @klent - i updated it to use `getFullYear` instead, how's that?

Comment: `new Date(p[2], p[0] - 1, p[1])` can you explain this part of the code? I also want to know how to add months. Thanks

Comment: Happy to help... [Here's a good reference function](https://gist.github.com/Pamblam/4d33935d712903da10c7366c20157d21) I wrote for formatting dates in any format you need. It's more managable than adding an entire library, but it's mostly just good for reference.

Answer (score 2):

In line with some of the comments and answers. I wrote a function that you can call which will format the date as you want it.

It accepts a JS Date as the only argument

```
var formatDate = (date) => {
   var month = date.getMonth() + 1
   var day = date.getDate()
   var year = date.getFullYear()

   //Pad the month and/or day with "0" if its not two digits
   if(month < 10) month = `0${month}`
   if(day < 10) day = `0${day}`

   return `${month}/${day}/${year}`
}
```

[JS Bin example](https://jsbin.com/temagiqopo/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: neat, +1, probly wanna pad the date too if it's less than 10.

Comment: this works too! I just had to add this to my current code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have the time stored in the `temp` variable.
So, you can do something like this to get it in your format.

```
formattedDate = ("0" + (temp.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + temp.getDate() + "/" + temp.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of date accept:

```
new Date(year, month [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

on your case:

```
new Date( year, month, day )
```

Below functions solves your problem:

```
function formatDate(date) {
    let parts = date.split('/');
    date = new Date( parts[2], parts[0]-2, parts[1] )
    return addZero( date.getMonth() + 1) +
        addZero( date.getDate()) + date.getFullYear();
}

function addZero(number) {
    return ('0' + number).slice(-2) + '/' ;
}

// test
var dateN = '01/31/2018'
console.log( formatDate(dateN) );
```